# Seam @Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION) behaves like request scoped

Tags: jsf, seam, conversation-scope

I am trying to implement a function where an `h:commandButton` component is used to produce a row of the `h:dataTable` with each button click. I'm testing this using a string list. When the page is first loaded, the function works fine, with the button click producing a row with value "New Item". however, when I click it the second time, the ArrayList from the ActionBean backbean seems to be reallocated. What am I doing wrong?

Action Bean:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.In;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Scope;
import org.jboss.seam.ScopeType;

import jp.co.dir.bf.common.AppLogger;
import jp.co.dir.bf.front.common.BaseBean;

@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
@Name("ActionBean")
public class ActionBean extends BaseBean {

    private AppLogger appLogger;
    private List<String> list  = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    public ActionBean() {
        
        appLogger = new AppLogger(Logger.getLogger(ActionBean.class));
    }
    public void init(){
        appLogger.showDebug("The Form is loaded");
                appLogger.showDebug("Initial Size: "+ list.size());

        
    }
    public AppLogger getAppLogger() {
        return appLogger;
    }
    public void setAppLogger(AppLogger appLogger) {
        this.appLogger = appLogger;
    }
    
    public List<String> getList(){
        return list;
    }
    
    public void addToList(){
        
        list.add(new String("New Item"));
               /////This is always printing 1 after each add.
        appLogger.showDebug("Item added: "+ list.size());
    }
    public void setList(List<String> list){
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

The xhtml:

```
<h:commandButton value = "Add New" >
<p:ajax listener="#{ActionBean.addToList}" update="table"/>
</h:commandButton>
            

<h:dataTable id = "table" value ="#{ActionBean.list}" var = "item">
    <h:column>
    <h:outputText value ="#{item}"/>
    </h:column>             
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: @balusc I'm new to JSF, so even though I know what went wrong, I'm not exactly sure why. If it's not too much trouble for you, can you give a brief explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue. It's the silliness on my part. I forgot to add the
`@Begin(join = true)` annotation on init() so init is getting called on each load, instead of being called only once for every conversation. Hope somebody finds this helpful. The new `Action Bean` code is now:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.In;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Scope;
import org.jboss.seam.ScopeType;

import jp.co.dir.bf.common.AppLogger;
import jp.co.dir.bf.front.common.BaseBean;

@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
@Name("ActionBean")
public class ActionBean extends BaseBean {

    private AppLogger appLogger;
    private List<String> list  = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    public ActionBean() {
        
        appLogger = new AppLogger(Logger.getLogger(ActionBean.class));
    }

    @Begin(join = true) ///this is the part that is updated
    public void init(){
        appLogger.showDebug("The Form is loaded");
                appLogger.showDebug("Initial Size: "+ list.size());

        
    }
    public AppLogger getAppLogger() {
        return appLogger;
    }
    public void setAppLogger(AppLogger appLogger) {
        this.appLogger = appLogger;
    }
    
    public List<String> getList(){
        return list;
    }
    
    public void addToList(){
        
        list.add(new String("New Item"));
               /////This is always printing 1 after each add.
        appLogger.showDebug("Item added: "+ list.size());
    }
    public void setList(List<String> list){
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```